# How to correctly do the aliasing for whois

Tags: bash, bash-alias

I'm trying to get this alias to work.

```
alias awhois='whois -h whois.cymru.com " -v $1"'
```

But bash doesn't give the same output.

```
# awhois 8.8.8.8
Error: no ASN or IP match on line 1.
AS      | IP               | AS Name
15169   | 8.8.8.8          | GOOGLE - Google LLC, US

# whois -h whois.cymru.com " -v 8.8.8.8"
AS      | IP               | BGP Prefix          | CC | Registry | Allocated  | AS Name
15169   | 8.8.8.8          | 8.8.8.0/24          | US | arin     | 1992-12-01 | GOOGLE - Google LLC, US
```

How can I make this works? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aliases don't recognize positional parameters. Use a function instead.

```
awhois()
{
  whois -h whois.cymru.com " -v $1"
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks! It works but when I do "source .bash_profile", it came out error.

``-bash: .bash_profile: line 55: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-bash: .bash_profile: line 55: `awhois()'``

Is this normal?

Comment: Are you sure you're using bash and not e.g. dash as your shell?

Comment: Yes, am using bash.

Shell: /bin/bash